# .NET Remoting Bind to All NICs

Tags: c#, .net, vpn, remoting

I am working on my companies .NET remoting server application to try and make it bind to all available NICs, so that it listens on multiple subnets.

The current way we do it is by telling the server to bind to a specific IP address and that has worked in the past, but when hosted on a server with multiple subnets the clients all need to be on the same subnet or they won't be able to speak to the server.

One solution I tried was to tell the server to bind to the machine name of the server it was running on using the following code:

```
 // If there is an IP present in the config to bind to, then bind on that specific IP.
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remotingBindTo))
 {
     props.Add("bindTo", remotingBindTo);
 }
 // Otherwise bind on the machine name, meaning the server should bind on all IP addresses.
 else
 {
     props.Add("machineName", Environment.MachineName);
     props.Add("useIpAddress", false);
 }

 // Create a new channel            
 IChannel channel = new TcpServerChannel(props, null);

 // Register the channel
 ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, remotingSecure);
```

That basically says if the servers config setting "RemotingBindTo" is set then we bind to the provided IP address otherwise we bind to the machine name.

The problem with this is if you use a VPN connection to connect a client to the server. When the client is creating a proxy to a server object it is trying to connect via the machine name and the client PC can not resolve that to an IP address. A work around to this was to place the name into the Windows hosts file and tell it to resolve to the VPN IP address, but because the VPN gives a different IP address every time this is not a viable solution.

I suppose my question is: Is it possible AT ALL to get a .NET remoting server to bind to all available NICs/IP addresses?

Has anyone else experienced anything similar?

Comment: One of the many reasons Remoting has been deprecated.  My suggestion would be to have your VPN administrator configure you VPN to always give your server the same IP address.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I know. Until I get some time to switch the thing to WCF it's just a matter of continuing trying to make remoting bend to my will! The client that reported the issue uses TeamViewer VPN, so I will have to find out if TV VPN can use static IP addresses as they have told me it is all dynamic.

Comment: I just tested this out and found that if I just initiate the channel as IChannel channel = new TcpServerChannel(1865); it listens on all IP addresses on the machine.

Comment: @a-h, This did not work for me. The server was able to be contacted from any IP address on the same subnet, but not different subnets.